# Bash using awk undesirable output

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to write a script that Highlights TODO comments in a directory or file.
The issue that I keep running into is that the I'm trying to have the following output format

> TODO: Here is what i need to do -> example-file.txt:linenumber

The parser won't grab the comment because  the ':' after the TODO.

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo "TODO highlighter..." 
grep -Hnr --color 'TODO' $* |  awk -F: '{print $'${@:3}'" -> "$1 ":" $2}'
```

here is the file ive been using to test (todo-example.java):

```
//TODO: Bobo region Description
//todo this is good but needs new name
//TODO- John fix
```

and this is the output:

```
//output 
todo-example.java:4://TODO: Bobo region Descriptiontodo-example.java:4
todo-example.java:29:   //TODO- John fix todo-example.java:29

//desired output 
//TODO: Bobo region Description -> todo-example.java:4
//TODO- John fix -> todo-example.java:29
```

I have tried changing the arguments but i cant seem to get the desired results of $3 to $N. Thanks.

Comment: using `grep` may misgrep some info if you have, say, `TODO` in a string. if you don't care such a minor case, you can put all the work inside of awk. it would be much easier.

Comment: I'm somewhat unfamiliar with awk. but I dont mind simplifying the command as long as it still does the format i posted above.

Comment: BTW, unquoted `$*` is bad juju -- if this is for a list of filenames, you almost certainly want `"$@"`, and maybe an explicit `/dev/null` preceding it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I realized what you were saying after i ran the script with no arguments and it went crazy.

Comment: Re: no-arguments case, putting an explicit `/dev/null` before your `"$@"` is a good idea if you don't want it to default to stdin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need the following line in your script:

```
awk '/TODO/ { print FILENAME": "NR" -> "$0 }' "$@"
```

to highlight `TODO`, you can trivially reuse your grep command:

```
awk '/TODO/ { print FILENAME": "NR" -> "$0 }' "$@" | grep --color 'TODO'
```

Comment: I switched the line to `awk '/TODO/ { print $0 "->" FILENAME ":"NR"" }' "$@"` but this is the answer. thank you!